# Integrating FB login to unity web player game

Tags: c#, facebook-login, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, unity-web-player

I integrated Facebook SDK with unity
to allow logging via Facebook
it worked well in unity editor
check here https://i.stack.imgur.com/f14th.png

```
void Start()
{
     FB.Init(FBINIDONE);
}
void FBINIDONE()
{
     string[] perms = { "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" };
     FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms,LognDone);
}
```

but after building the game - the login did not work

1-locally -> did not work

2-online host -> did not work

3-Facebook canvas -> did not work

I googled too much , any other help ?

Comment: so you went [step by step all the way through the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/canvas) and it still does not work?

Comment: Hi ,
after following this step by step , the game files does not load
failed to download game data error message in chrome and not loading in firefox

Comment: I had to do a WebGL game on fb canvas an year ago and had some similar problems. Funny they haven't been fixed yet. What I did was write a bridge from Unity to browser and write all the fb functionality in a browser plugin in javascript. Google "Unity browser plugins" for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but alot of the tutorials or step by step guides I found were outdated and would have errors like this if you tried them. I think this updated one might help if you have not already tried it

[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fuhQDTNVGk&annotation_id=annotation_1019767461&feature=iv&src_vid=nmeMHY5D4SI)

Comment: Did this answer your question, or was the information helpful?